# P/Invoke - C# signature for Custom Types using DLLImport?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

```
void MyUnmanagedFunc(
          CustomClass&   szOutputData
        , ICustomObject* pDataObject
        , const LPCWSTR   szTag
        , const LPCWSTR   szDisplay = NULL
        , const BOOL      bAdd = TRUE
    );
```

I have the above signature of a function defined in a C++ DLL say, `abc.dll`. I am not able to create the proper method signature in C#. Note, that the `CustomClass` is defined in sometherfile, say, `xyz.dll` and with `__declspec(dllexport)`. I tried [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe) tool to generate the signature.

Sorry, if I have repeated the question. I have tried to search over before posting.

Comment: You cannot pinvoke functions that take a C++ class object as an argument.  You have to write a wrapper in the C++/CLI language.

Comment: You need a lot more information before you can get an answer. In particular: what is `CustomClass` and `ICustomObject`?

Comment: CustomCLass is a basic C++ string wrapper class and ICustomObject is a COM interface. It has an idl definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is to create mixed assembly written in C++. It can include any necessary headers and call method above from abc.dll and it can expose managed wrapper in the same time.

Comment: It would be great if you can point to some basic sample of what you are talking about.

Comment: 1) Add new C++ project to your solution with 'Common Language Runtime Support /clr' enabled in General settings. Include any headers necessary related to abc and/or xyz. 2) Then create in this C++ project new public ref class AbcWrapper (or better). Inside AbcWrapper call your 'native' code.
3) Use your AbcWrapper class in your managed code.

Comment: abc.dll has a .def file with the function entry points defined and it already includes the required headers too. So, is it really necessary to create a managed C++ wrapper ? Just DllImport should work if I know how to deal with custom types? But, I will try what you are suggesting.

Comment: Option to creating mixed intemediate C++ assembly is to create in abc.dll wrapper function MyUnmanagedFuncWrp with szOutputData as e.g. const char* or similar and pDataObject can be used in C# code as System.IntPtr.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. But, I also figured out that since I have the luxury of changing the COM code, I will attach the method in the IDL file of the interface which has already been exposed as part of the .NET interop assembly. So, anybody who upgrades will recompile and build against these Interop assemblies.